# How do I find an element in Python[Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I want to get the following element but I'm struggling to do so. I've tried by class, css_selector, etc.

```
<a href="http://www.google.ca" target="_blank" class="btn visit__link">
"Visit this Webpage"
<br>
"for more content!"
</a>
<br>
<small>Opens in a new window.</small>
</div>
</section>
```

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
web = browser.find_element(By.cssSelector("a[class='btn visit__link']")).click()
```

Comment: have you tried `By.cssSelector('.visit__link')`?

Comment: This doesn't look like the Python driver of Selenium.

Comment: `browser.find_element_by_class_name('visit__link')`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to locate the link *by the class name* as @Malik suggested:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('visit__link')
```

or with a CSS selector:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.visit__link')
```

Or, you can also locate the link by the *partial link text*:

```
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Visit this Webpage')
```

---

You may also need to [*wait*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) *for the button to become visible*:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Visit this Webpage")))
link.click()
```

Comment: Why am I getting this error:
    wait = WebdriverWait(browser, 10)
    NameError: name 'WebdriverWait' is not defined

Comment: @Throwaway012 sure, it was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector:

```
By.cssSelector("a[class*='visit__link']")
```